# JMeter with Socket IO namespace error

Tags: sockets, socket.io, jmeter

Can anyone tell me how to connect to **default Socket IO namespace** using JMeter?

I am trying to connect to **Simple socket IO** app using JMeter, using the **default namespace**.
Now I want to send data to the web app using **socket IO** for testing.

It is giving the following **error :**

> **no socket for namespace undefined**

I am sending messages in the following order from JMeter.

```
2probe

3probe

5

40/

5::/:42["chat", {testData:"hello world"}]
```

Comment: Hi @Omer Malik, have you tried any plugin?